# Alloy UI editable select tag

Tags: jsp, alloy-ui

Is there any way, how user can input his own value to the aui:select component? I want the user to select an option from the drop-down list or add his own option.

Example:

```
<aui:select name="city" label="What city do you prefer?" id="selectedCity">
    <aui:option value="Moskau" label="Moskau" />
    <aui:option value="New York" label="New York"/>
    <aui:option value="London" label="London"/>
    <aui:option value="Berlin" label="Berlin" />
</aui:select>
```

This select creates a dropdown list with 4 cities, but I want to enable user to put there his own city.

Answer (score 1):

You can not input data in select component instead try adding one another option with value **other**. Also try getting cities dynamically rather than static. If user selects other than you can open a `text box` and ask user to input his/her city and than enter that city in database so that it can be used other time.